# combining two rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say that we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'from': [103, 102, 104, 105],
        'to': [104, 105, 103, 102],
        'id': [1] * 4,
        'p': [415, 1203.11, -414.35, -1197.37],
        'q': [0, -395.44, 62.23, 489.83]
    })
```

or

```
     from      to  id        p       q
0     103     104   1   415.00    0.00
1     102     105   1  1203.11 -395.44
2     104     103   1  -414.35   62.23
3     105     102   1 -1197.37  489.83
```

The goal is to combine the rows that have the same `from` and `to` values. In the example above, rows 0 and 2, and rows 1 and 3, needs to be combined.

The output is supposed to be as follows:

```
   from      to  id        p       q       p1      q1
0   103     104   1   415.00    0.00  -414.35   62.23
1   102     105   1  1203.11 -395.44 -1197.37  489.83
```

Of course, the following is also acceptable:

```
     from   to  id        p       q       p1      q1
0     104  103   1  -414.35   62.23   415.00    0.00
1     105  102   1 -1197.37  489.83  1203.11 -395.44
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sorting both columns `from` and `to` by [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html?highlight=sort#numpy.sort), then create counter `Series` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with sorting second level by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), last flatten `MultiIndex` with `f-strings` and convert `Multiindex in index` to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df[['from','to']] = np.sort(df[['from','to']], axis=1)
g = df.groupby(['from','to']).cumcount()

df = df.set_index(['from','to','id', g]).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
   from      to  id       p0      q0       p1      q1
0   103     104   1   415.00    0.00  -414.35   62.23
1   444  999230   1  1203.11 -395.44 -1197.37  489.83
```

Comment: Thank you very much. `df` is a large dataframe and I am worried that if we group by cumulative sum in order to find the rows that need to be merged, we may end up combining wrong ones if other combinations of numbers give the same cumulative sum. How can we go around this issue?

Comment: @Ali - hmmm, is possible use `g = df.groupby(['from','to'], sort=False).cumcount()` ?

Comment: I made an edit, so we have the case were we end up with the same cumsum. I tried cumcount on it and it works. Brilliant! Thank you @jezrael. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
#sort from and to first
df[['from', 'to']]=np.sort(df[['from', 'to']])
(
    df.groupby(['from', 'to'])
    #groupby and concatenate all q and q in the same group to 1 row
    .apply(lambda x:  x[['p','q']].values.reshape(1,-1)[0])
    #convert the list of p and q to a DataFrame
    .pipe(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist(), index=x.index))
    #rename the columns
    .rename(columns=lambda x: f'p{x//2}')
    .reset_index()
)

    from    to      p0      p0      p1          p1
0   103     104     415.00  0.00    -414.35     62.23
1   444     999230  1203.11 -395.44 -1197.37    489.83
```

Comment: Thank you Allen. If you don't mind, would you please explain each part of the solution? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just added some comments.